# .NET code execution at normal process exit?

Tags: .net, equivalent, atexit

In `C` there is the [atexit](http://man.he.net/man3/atexit) function, which

> The atexit() function registers the given function to be called at normal process termination, either via exit(3) or via return from the program's main().

Python has a similar capability.

Does .NET provide a way to call code at normal process termination? I know there are certain things like `DomainUnload` and `ProcessExit`, but at least as far as I can tell, these are unreliable - either requiring the application to be a Windows Forms (or WPF app), or something else. I am writing code for a .dll, so I can't rely on things like mucking with the main program function - wrapping it in a try/catch.

My ultimate goal is to perform some file cleanup (i.e. flush buffers and close). If I can call some unmanaged code, e.g. a win32api hook or something, I'm perfectly fine with that.

Comment: You could try CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT event of SetConsoleCtrlHandler.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no straight-forward answer that I know of.

If you want to write a robust DLL, you should prepare for several scenarios:

1. Your code is hosted in a .NET application, in the default AppDomain. (the trivial scenario)
2. Your code is hosted in a .NET application, in an AppDomain created by the host's code.
3. Your code is hosted in an unmanaged application (which hosts the CLR).

The 3rd scenario is the hardest to deal with, since the CLR can be disabled by its host, so managed code won't execute anymore.

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.ApplicationExit` is no good since it only applies to WinForm applications.

`System.AppDomain.DomainUnload` by itself is no good since it is never raised for the default AppDomain.

`AppDomain.ProcessExit` by itself is no good: if your code is hosted in a separate AppDomain, the host might unload that AppDomain, so the event will never raise.

I'd start by trying to cover most cases, using something like:

```
if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain())
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += MyTerminationHandler;
else
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += MyTerminationHandler;
```

But do notice the following remark ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx)):

> The total execution time of all ProcessExit event handlers is limited, just as the total execution time of all finalizers is limited at process shutdown. The default is two seconds. An unmanaged host can change this execution time by calling the ICLRPolicyManager::SetTimeout method with the OPR_ProcessExit enumeration value.

The above code still leaves the 3rd scenario unattended.
There are two methods I know of for dealing with that scenario (along with the first two)

First, you can use the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup` method, as follows:

```
{
//  this goes at your code's entry point
    RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(MyExecutionCode, MyCleanupCode, null);
}
static void MyExecutionCode(object data) { /* your execution code here */}
static void MyCleanupCode(object data, bool exceptionThrown) { /* your cleanup code here */ }
```

Second, you can utilize the `System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution.CriticalFinalizerObject` class ([see MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject.aspx)) by inheriting it and putting your cleanup code in the finalizer. This requires your cleanup code to adhere to the [Constrained Execution Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx) guidelines.

Comment: I think that either I'm going to go with the `CriticalFinalizerObject`, or use the `Critical/SafeHandle`. I actually just stumbled on this today but haven't had time to implement/test it, but I'm thinking it should provide what I want.